# Color issue for Bootstrap progress bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using Bootstrap CSS (Bootstrap v2.3.1). I am trying to display multiple progress bar on the page. For that i have written code as given below-

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="10">
    <td>
      <div class="progress progress-striped active span2" id="11">
        <span style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">50%</span>
        <div class="bar" style="width: 50%;" id="111"></div>
      </div>                    
    </td>
  </tr>         
  <tr>
    <td id="20">
      <div class="progress progress-striped active span2" id="12">
        <span style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">100%</span>
        <div class="bar" style="width: 100%;" id="112"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have given 50 and 100 width value to these progress bar after that they show same color for both.

[image]

Color of first progress bar get reflected in second progress bar. Is there any mistake from my side?

Comment: You use the same code for both progress bar, why would you want to have different colors?

Comment: Actually i want to display multiple progress bar dynamically using loop and with different value. As per the value color will be different

Comment: You have to do this by yourself, bootstrap doesn't automatically change the color of the progress bar. Just add the class that correspond to the value in your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have different progress bar colors, use the classes `progress-info, progress-success, progress-warning, progress-danger` as described in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#progress):

```
<div class="progress progress-info">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 20%"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress progress-success">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 40%"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress progress-warning">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 60%"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress progress-danger">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 80%"></div>
</div>
```